# How to query excel document using sql

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I would like to query an excel document using sql. I want to use c# and ado to perform the query.  I don't want to install office on the server. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use a csv instead of the excel file. Mysql and sqlserver both have ways to use a csv file and read the data.

Comment: @Nived I have edited the question

Comment: Could you [create a dataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300043/convert-a-byte-array-into-datatable) from the byte array and query that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an OleDB connection to access your Excel spreadsheet, here is an example using DataTables

```
string connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", "myDocument.xlsx");

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable", connString);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds, "TheData");
DataTable theTable = ds.Tables["TheData"];
```

Once you have done this you can access values like

```
theTable.Rows[indexOfRow].ItemArray[indexOfItem] //The items are stored as objects
```

**This specific example is for .xlsx files**

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Is there a way to do this without saving the file to disk? Perhaps, query excel that is loaded in memory.

Comment: @Luke101 care to expand, maybe give an example? :)

Comment: In the connection it has "myDocument.xlsx". This means I have to save the file to disk first. I have a byte array of the excel file. Is there a way to query the byte array instead? Without saving the excel file to disk.

Comment: @Luke101 Sorry, I'm not sure how to do that in all honesty, this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490526/how-to-query-excel-data-which-is-in-memory-using-oledb has someone saying you can't and another saying that software they made can do it, but that's all I can help with there

Comment: I always thought Extended Properties had to be `Excel 12.0 Xml` for the openXML format?